# Conditional statement, etc. organizing in gedit

Tags: editor, text-editor, conditional-statements, gedit

I was wondering if it was possible to group/organize conditional statement blocks in gedit in much the same manner as notepad++, via a plug-in or other means.
Thanks to all in advance.
http://i50.tinypic.com/2vuyd5f.png (Image, for reference.)

Answer (score 0):

No, gedit doesn't have code folding, however this plugin:
http://code.google.com/p/gedit-folding/ 
claims to provide code folding in gedit. Though I've never used that plugin.